# how to show two web pages in one window without frames

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to show a web page within another web web in asp.net. I have a page named `home.aspx` and a page name `add.aspx` how can i do this.

Comment: dont forget to marks answer as accpeted if you got the info you want ..

Answer (score 0):

if you just want to load contenct than make use of jquery ajax function or noraml ajax to load data in you page

Example

```
$("#result").load("AjaxPages/Page.aspx", function () {
    alert("Page.html has been loaded successfully!")
});
```

Comment: thank you for your advice,one more question is that iframe is better than this

Comment: i think nowdays for functinaly like this its better to go for the loading data in div using ajax rather than going for frames

Answer (score 0):

Use iframes. Pleace for example this code inside the homep.aspx. This is only the idea, find how to show it with out border and with out scrool bars, and also how to fit it in place.

```
<iframe src="add.aspx"></iframe>
```

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp
http://htmlhelp.com/reference/html40/special/iframe.html

### ajax and iframe

Use ajax if you have some informations only to show. Use iframe if you also need independend post backs that enters data.

ajax is better if you care to have only one page, not working with out javascript, and maybe you need to add more ajax to make more thinks with the data that you get.

iframe is fast, but 'dirty' because is not seo friendly, a user can open content from iframe alone, etc.